# C++ template with variadic argument specialization for number of arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-specialization

What is the best way to generate a specialization for a (class) template which accepts variadic template arguments.

In my usecase I have a class which accepts a number of integers and I want a specialization for the case that there is only one integer as argument but the value of the integer can be arbitrary.

For example:

```cpp
template <int a, int ...b>
class c {
    private:
        c<b...> otherClass;
}

template <int a>
class c {
     // Some base case
}
```

Is this possible to do this or what is the easiest way to achieve such a specialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal template specialization would be enough if I understand your question correctly.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int a, int ...b>
struct c {
    c() { std::cout << "Normal" << std::endl; }
};

template <int a>
struct c<a> {
     c() { std::cout << "Special" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    c<1,2> c1;
    c<2> c2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Class template specializations have the template parameters appended to the class name as such:

```
template <int a>
class c<a> {};
       ^^^
```

Comment: Using this syntax i just get the error: "error: non-class, non-variable partial specialization ‘c<a>’ is not allowed"